# MySQL order by LOCATE results in Out of sort memory error

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query where I am trying to query for matching records with a `where like %` that's causing `Out of sort memory` error

The query in question looks like this:

```sql
select *
from `collections`
where (`policy_id` like '%apple%' or `name` like '%apple%')
order by LOCATE('apple', `name`)
limit 10 offset 0;
```

So I am searching for the term `apple` in the `collection` table (with approx 80k rows) and using `order by LOCATE` to return the most closest match to the top.

I did a quick check to see how many results were matching without using the order by and limit, and there were only 16 rows

Any idea why this particular query is resulting in `Out of sort memory` error?

The database is version is MySQL 8 (RDS), and the table schema is:

```sql
create table collections
(
    id                 bigint unsigned auto_increment   primary key,
    policy_id          varchar(64)                      not null,
    name               varchar(255)                     not null,
    constraint         collections_policy_id_unique unique (policy_id)
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index collections_name_index
    on collections (name);
```

Comment: This might be related to the issue I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76557503/mysql-8-0-33-error-when-selecting-json-column-out-of-sort-memory-consider-inc/76557997#76557997

Comment: You may find this URL useful to better understand how to use LOCATE - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-functions/mysql-locate-function/   Good luck.