# Getting out of sort memory buffer while I use order by and use join (right join)

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory

Query:

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        parent.*,
        child.key,
        child.value,
        totalGrossWeight as totalWeight
    from
        child
    right join parent on
        parent.code = child.code) as parent
where
    true
order by
    parent.changedAt desc,
    code asc
limit 100
```

Exception:
`SQL Error [1038] [HY001]: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size`

I don't get this exception if I remove the join or obviously if I don't use order by. I don't want to increase the buffer size. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: The best solution is to optimize the order by with an index. If the query reads data in the desired order, then the query doesn't need to use the sort buffer.

Comment: Please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76557997/20860 It might explain why you are getting the out of memory error.